# FullCalendar React - How to use selectConstraint With Background Events of Display Background & Inverse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

How would I go about not allowing users to click on background events that are greyed out in Full Calendar?

For my current calendar, I am trying to display available bookings for a tutoring company and I currently have tutor availabilities and tutor lessons

I am currently able to allow users to not click on greyed out areas from the following array:

```
let availabilities = [{
      groupId: "lesson-available",
      daysOfWeek: ["1"],
      startTime: "12:00:00",
      endTime: "15:00:00",
      display: "inverse-background",
      color: "#ccc",
    },
    {
      groupId: "lesson-available",
      daysOfWeek: ["2"],
      startTime: "15:00:00",
      endTime: "16:00:00",
      display: "inverse-background",
      color: "#ccc",
    },
];
```

But I would like to be able to make the following lessons unavailable on the calendar and not be clickable also:

```
let lessons = [{
   groupId: "lesson-unavailable",
   start: "2021-01-18T13:00:00",
   end: "2021-01-18T14:00:00",
   display: "background",
   color: "#ccc",
},
{
   groupId: "lesson-unavailable",
   start: "2021-01-19T15:00:00",
   end: "2021-01-19T16:00:00",
   display: "background",
   color: "#ccc",
}
];
```

My Code for my Calendar is the following:

```
<FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        headerToolbar={{
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
        }}
        height="auto"
        initialView="timeGridWeek"
        editable={true}
        eventColor="#6DCBCA"
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        allDaySlot={true}
        weekends={true}
        events={currentEvents}
        select={handleDateSelect}
        eventContent={renderEventContent}
        eventClick={handleEventClick}
        eventDrop={handleEventDrop}
        eventDragStart={handleEventDragStart}
        eventDragStop={handleEventDragStop}
        selectConstraint={"lesson-available"}
      />
```

As you can see, the following constraint of

```
selectConstraint={"lesson-available"}
```

is disabling me to click on anything else but the availabilities array which is perfect, but how would I edit this to also incorporate not being able to click on the lessons array (which is displayed as background, not inverse-background)

In my image:

Even though the 3-4pm on the 19th of Jan is greyed out, I am still able to click on it. This is exactly what I need to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `selectOverlap` function, in addition to your `selectConstraint`, to achieve this.

The documentation for selectOverlap says:

> ...the function will be called once for every time the user’s selection
> intersects with an event. If the function returns true, the selection
> will be allowed. If false, the selection will not be allowed.

```
 selectOverlap: function(event) {
  return !(event.groupId == "lesson-unavailable");
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEpwyqm

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!